# How do I change the color/Style for the Document Map in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, colors

For Notepad++ I use the document map a lot, however since I changed the styles around for Batch code it has this strange brown and blue coloring. I've been trying to figure out how to change at least the brown color, however I have found no style settings with any type of brown. What settings would I change to modify the Document Map Colors? [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this page while searching for an answer to this same question.

Turns out support for customizing the Document Map style was added to [Notepad++ 8.1.5](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21894/notepad-v8-1-5-released).

But it still doesn't appear in the Style Configurator in Global Styles.  I had to manually add it to my current theme.xml file in `%AppData%\Notepad++\themes` (paste that line into a folder window address bar to go there).

Find and edit your current theme file in `%AppData%\Notepad++\themes` to add this line to the `<GlobalStyles>` section:

```
<WidgetStyle name="Document map" styleID="0" fgColor="707070" bgColor="303030" />
```

This will start you off with a dark gray background and a lighter gray highlight.

Save the file, close it, and if you used Notepad++ to make the edit, switch to a different theme and back.  Open the Style Configurator and now Document Map should appear in the Style: box with Global Styles selected.  Its position in the list will match that of where you put it in the XML file.

Comment: In 8.2.1, these settings don't work. The highlight still comes out as that brown colour; and the background stays at some particular dark grey no matter what you set them to in the Style Configurator.

Comment: Make sure the second 'm' in "Document map" is lower case?

Comment: Funny; it works now. I'm sure I copied and pasted the line exactly as it appears in the answer here the first time, just as I did now. Now that it's working, I reversed the colours in my setting, because I like it better that way. (Dark background for the section that's in view, 'fogged out' background for the section(s) that are out of view.)